# IDEA resource files missing after updating

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Files miss from the target folder After I update these files in resource folder.The IDE is IDEA and the project is maven project.

> Here is the picture of project files

[the project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5qMB.png)

> Here is the configuration of the IDEA project structure

[the IDEA project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Gl8.png)

Can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Please be more clear. Remove links to images (we can't easily reference what's in the images when we're talking about the problem) and be more descriptive.

Comment: @GlenPierce We know things in target folder are the project class files and resource files after compiled,but when I update the resource file in my   project ,it's removed from the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try re import all maven project option from maven dialog box.

Comment: First time it's work, but the file missed again once I try to update it.Is there any solutions to solve this problems completely？

Answer (score 0):

target folder is generated by maven install.
Unless you have something explicitilly removing them they should appear normally when runnig mvn clean install.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Thanks first.My `pom.xml` does't have any `<exclude>` tags.